Error when installing openssl-devel [sss_cache] DB version too old
I am building a RHEL8 instance and when installing openssl-devel and python36-devel I get the error

[sss_cache] [sysdb_domain_cache_connect] (0x0010): DB version too old
[0.23], expected [0.24] for domain implicit_files!
Higher version of database is expected! In order to upgrade the
database, you must run SSSD.
Removing cache files in /var/lib/sss/db should fix the issue, but note
that removing cache files will also remove all of your cached
credentials.

I added sss_cache -E before the openssl-devel install step but that didn't help.. I also tried restarting the sssd service and the error still appears every time
